# Karma Plugin File Location

Tags: file, installation, npm, karma-runner

When installing a Karma plugin like so:

```
npm install karma-jasmine
```

where does NPM actually download the physical files? And how does Karma know they are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It installs them in the same directory as Karma itself. So the structure looks something like:

```
node_modules
  - karma
  - karma-jasmine
```